# confidence interval of estimates with sumcoding

Tags: statistical-significance, confidence-interval, glmm

I am using `sumcoding` for my treatments in my design matrix $X$, as such I leave one treatment out and estimate these as follows `X_missing = 0- sum(other treatments)`.

I am using `confint` to estimate the  confidence interval of the fixed treatment effects, but since `X_missing` is calculated manually I can't really calculate the confidence interval of the missing treatment. Is there a way to work around this?

Answer (score 0):

I've eventually chosen for the most simple solution: set a different treatment as a reference in my sumcoding.